# Is one Android activity enough with phonegap

Tags: android, phonegap-4.0.0, phonegap-cli, phonegap-developer-app

I just started developing mobile app with phonegap.
I want to check the best practice in maintaining screens. 
Is it possible to have only one activity and navigating screens with html's. 
If so is it correct practice?

Besides, when we need to maintain activities and corresponding html's on t top of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

navigating screens with html's means using WebView and act like a browser?

If the project is small and you are the only developer, Yes. Can have only one activity. and navigate through various fragments is possible. but not very recommend. One of the reasons is, with only one activity make it difficult for team work.